# ImageMagick and mogrify crop

Tags: php, imagemagick, mogrify

I have having problems getting a crop to work on an image (I have got the resize working fine)

The orginal image is `x` and after a resize:

```
mogrify -resize x75 /my/path/image.jpg
```

i can see the resize has worked properly after performing getimagesize():

```
Array
(
    [0] => 148
    [1] => 75
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="148" height="75"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

the crop command is:

```
mogrify -crop 100x75! +0+0 /my/path/image.jpg
```

Once this is complete I try and confirm the image is the correct size by using `getimagesize()` but i get the following error and I also can't access the image.

```
Warning (2): getimagesize(/my/path/image.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? Am i using the wrong syntax for the crop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the error was in the syntax there is no space between the image size and crop position. **it should look like this**:

```
mogrify -crop 100x75!+0+0 /my/path/image.jpg
```

the below is **incorrect**:

```
mogrify -crop 100x75! +0+0 /my/path/image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember which path I used previously but I found that the only way I could get the image size was to use a direct link to the file http://www.blablabla - Have you done that or are you using the PHP path?

On a sidenote I thought you were meant to set the filename twice for it to open and then save the file?

```
mogrify -crop 100x75! +0+0 /my/path/image.jpg /my/path/image.jpg
```

I hope this helps you out mate...